# create ftp connection using drupal

Tags: files

I have made my own module, that has a form where the user can upload a file.
Once the file has been collected, Drupal should open an FTP connection to a server and upload the file into it.
I have found "Storage API" and "Media Move" modules that seems to have this kind of functionality, but I have no clue on how use those modules with my custom code.
How do I make an FTP connection from Drupal to an external server and upload the file?

Comment: Does the other server support PHP , then this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135787/upload-file-with-php-to-another-php-server

Comment: @Terix: Looking for Same issue.Did you complete this task.

Comment: I suggest uploading of files(long background jobs) should be done by a cron job instead.

Answer (score 1):

[cURL](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) ist the perfect library for this. It's available on most PHP servers. Check [this for an example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/ftpupload.html).